# Can we use Bouncy Castle to store and use this 5 CRT files dynamically

Tags: java, spring, ssl, bouncycastle, keystore

We have 5 customers with 5 CRT files and a single spring boot app to manage SSL communications with a third party API.

Configuring one CRT into the keystore we can communicate flawlessly with the third party API.

Now, the question is, can we use Bouncy Castle to store and use this 5 CRT files dynamically?
Also, they can be stored programatically?

If not, there is any other way?
We are using RestTemplate for our connections.

Comment: In addition to @ioan-m answer, I would recommend you to use also KeystoreExplorer: https://keystore-explorer.org/
With this tool it is fairly easy to create .jks files. Once you have all certificates in one place (trust-store), you can place it as part of your rest caller? Which class do you use to call 3rd party api?

Comment: @MihailoStupar, the keystore-explorer is a great tool, we are using it to build the keystore. Now we are looking to it programatically. We are using the RestTemplate class do call the 3rd party api. Do you have any examples on how to chose the right cert to begin the communication?

Comment: I am just trying to understand. Do you use certificates for client authentication (we can call it as 2-way-ssl)? Or those 5 clients have i.e. self-signed certificates so your java program does not trust them, is this the case? I think that in both cases this link could be helpful (https://medium.com/@itzgeoff/using-a-custom-trust-store-with-resttemplate-in-spring-boot-77b18f6a5c39).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Java Keystore API. You have a detailed explanation on how to manage keystores programatically here:
[Java Keystore API usage example](https://www.baeldung.com/java-keystore)

Comment: This is almost a link-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Please note that creation of `RestTemplate` is time consuming, so you should create 5 `RestTemplate` beans for your 5 connections and later just consume them. They are in any case thread-safe.

```java
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

----------------------------------------------------------------------

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                .loadKeyMaterial( file_jks, password)      // path to your .jks file with its password
                                                           // (it can be also .p12), 
                                                           // note that this method is important if 
                                                           // SERVER expects your CLIENT certificate for connection. 
                                                           // It is also called 2-way-ssl
                .loadTrustMaterial( file_jks , password)   // path yo your .jks file with its password. 
                                                           // (again, it can be .p12)
                                                           // you will use this method if SERVER has i.e. self-signed certificate
                                                           // or any other certificate that is not trusted by CA
                .setProtocol("TLS1.2")                
                .build();
        
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                .build();


        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = 
                new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
```

Besides `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency, you should also import

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${change-version}</version>
        </dependency>
```